# Barclays epdq payment page display the payment option one below the other instead of side by side

Tags: php, magento

I am integrating Barclays epdq pspid with my magento website and I want to change the layout of the payment page to display the payment options one below the other and not side by side as shown in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can arrange the layout/list of the payment methods on our payment page using the following hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="PMLISTTYPE" value="">
```

0: Horizontally grouped logos with the group name on the left (default
value)
1: Horizontally grouped logos with no group names
2: Vertical list of logos with specific payment method or brand name

So to display the payment options with groupnames one below the other

```
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="OWNERTELNO" value="'.$billphone.'">';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="OWNERTOWN" value="'.$bill2.'">';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="OWNERZIP" value="'.$billpostcode.'">';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="PMLIST" value="'.$cardvalue.'">';
    //ranjani
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="PMLISTTYPE" value="2">';
    //Fix
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="PSPID" value="'.$pspid.'">';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="SHASIGN" value="'.$shasig.'">';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="ORDERSHIPMETH" value="'.$shippingdescription.'">';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="ORDERSHIPCOST" value="'.$shippingamount.'">';
```